# Python TypeError - Expected bytes but got 'str' when trying to created signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, hmac, coinbase-api

I'm trying to create a signature for an API call - for which the documentation provides these instructions:

```
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or '')
    signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

However, I always get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str' 

File "/Users/dylanbrandonuom/BouncePay_Code/src/coinbase/Coinbase_API.py", line 26, in __call__
signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

File "/Users/dylanbrandonuom/BouncePay_Code/src/coinbase/Coinbase_API.py", line 40, in <module>
r = requests.get(api_url + 'user', auth=auth)
```

I've tried changing

```
signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

to

```
signature = hmac.new(b'self.secret_key', message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

but had no success.

Here is the second part of the error:

```
api_url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/'
auth = CoinbaseWalletAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
r = requests.get(api_url + 'user', auth=auth)
```

Is anyone able to let me know why this keeps occurring?

I'm thinking it might be the message variable with `request.method` and `request.path_url`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message you're seeing tells you that you're passing a (unicode) string as the `key` argument to `hmac.new()`, but it expects bytes (or a bytearray).

This means that `self.secret_key` is a string, rather than a bytes object. There's no indication in your question where in your code `self.secret_key` is being assigned, but on the assumption that it's a constant somewhere, it might look like this:

```
SECRET = 'some secret key'
```

If so, changing that line to something like

```
SECRET = b'some secret key'
```

… ought to work. If you're assigning `self.secret_key` in some other way, it's impossible to know how to fix the problem without seeing that code.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. I had declared them as strings. Thank you very much!