# Typer Error : Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, unicode, hmac, rest, hashlib

I want to work with RestAPI from kaufland.de website. I followed the instruction to sign a request from  : [this website](https://www.kaufland.de/api/v1/?page=rest-api) .

Here is the code, they gave me as an example to run to sign a request by a SHA-256 HMAC in base64 encoding:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import time

def sign_request(method, uri, body, timestamp, secret_key):
    plain_text = "\n".join([method, uri, body, str(timestamp)])

    digest_maker = hmac.new(secret_key, '', hashlib.sha256)
    digest_maker.update(plain_text)
    return digest_maker.hexdigest()

method = "POST"
uri = "https://www.kaufland.de/api/v1/units/"
body = ""
timestamp = time.time()
secret_key = "83cfe0909f4e57f05dd403"

print(sign_request(method, uri, body, timestamp, secret_key))
```

But the code above threw an error :

```
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'
```

I found a solution from [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791095/python-typeerror-expected-bytes-but-got-str-when-trying-to-created-signature), added b in front of secret_key :

```
secret_key = b'83cfe0909f4e57f05dd403'
```

However, it still threw an error when I run :

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

So I followed the solution from [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763235/unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing-error) by importing base64 package :

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
import base64

def sign_request(method, uri, body, timestamp, secret_key):
    plain_text = "\n".join([method, uri, body, str(timestamp)])

    digest_maker = hmac.new(secret_key, '', hashlib.sha256)
    digest_maker.update(plain_text)
    return base64.b64encode(digest_maker.hexdigest())

method = "POST"
uri = "https://www.kaufland.de/api/v1/units/"
body = ""
timestamp = time.time()
secret_key = b"a7d0cb1da1ddbc86c96ee5fedd341b7d8ebfbb2f5c83cfe0909f4e57f05dd403"

print(sign_request(method, uri, body, timestamp, secret_key))
```

But it still threw an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-54-83e727ea1edf>", line 22, in <module>
    print(sign_request(method, uri, body, timestamp, secret_key))

  File "<ipython-input-54-83e727ea1edf>", line 10, in sign_request
    digest_maker = hmac.new(secret_key, '', hashlib.sha256)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\hmac.py", line 153, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\hmac.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.update(msg)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\hmac.py", line 96, in update
    self.inner.update(msg)

TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Anyone can help me in this case ?

Comment: Isn't it the content that needs to be encoded, ie. `plaintext` in your case?

Comment: It complains about `msg` at that point. If you follow up the stack, it seems to be the `''` passed to `hmac.new()`. In any case, whoever gave you that example may be stuck with Python 2, which puts doubt on all the code.

Comment: Thanks, @UlrichEckhardt for your insight. I haven't coded in Python 2 so I don't know about it :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode your `secret_key` parameter on assign or in `hmac.new`.

Example:

```
secret_key = "83cfe0909f4e57f05dd403".encode('utf-8')
```

Or like I wrote above:

```
digest_maker = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), '', hashlib.sha256)
```

---

Upd:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import time

def sign_request(method, uri, body, timestamp, secret_key):
    plain_text = "\n".join([method, uri, body, str(timestamp)])

    digest_maker = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), msg=''.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=digestmod)
    digest_maker.update(plain_text.encode('utf-8'))
    return digest_maker.hexdigest()

method = "POST"
uri = "https://www.kaufland.de/api/v1/units/"
body = ""
timestamp = time.time()
secret_key = "a7d0cb1da1ddbc86c96ee5fedd341b7d8ebfbb2f5c83cfe0909f4e57f05dd403"
digestmod = hashlib.sha256

print(sign_request(method, uri, body, timestamp, secret_key))
```

Comment: Thank you but I still got the same error : TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: @mht Added update for my comment, tried on my side and it works

Comment: Thanks. It works. But can you explain why you wrote that code ?

Comment: @mht Updated once again based on your last example. A I got it correct, error was occurred there `digest_maker.update(plain_text)` because `plain_text` is also string and not bytes. So I encoded it too and it works without base64 lib

Comment: Try running `"83cfe0909f4e57f05dd403".encode('utf-8') == b'83cfe0909f4e57f05dd403'`, just FYI. ;)

Comment: Sure it could be just used with `.encode('utf-8')` but it should be done for `secret_key`, msg parameter for `hmac.new` and for `plain_text`